# Solving the issue of users who leave after getting their answer -- without accepting it

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Bolstered by evidence from [How to Solve the “New Users Who Don't Return” Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68410/how-to-solve-the-new-users-who-dont-return-problem)

It's a common problem across the sites that users -- new, old, and apathetic -- will sometimes leave their question without accepting an answer for an inordinate amount of time (usually to the extent of "ever").

I thusly request adding an answer acceptance timer or an option for those with enough rep to vote to accept an answer.

While some questions have no immediate answers (like questions about plot elements in unreleased films), many questions have clear and decisive answers that deserve commendation.

Perhaps tying it to the number of votes for the existing answers? Surely a bad answer - which the asker could change if they ever returned -- is better than no answer at all.

Comment: Is this really that big of an "issue"? So someone doesn't get 15 points of rep... big deal?

Comment: Everyone has reputation to accept an answer. The timer doesn't seem to be that warranted. And the use is asked to accept it when they first join the site. Not sure if anything can really be done.

Comment: @Catija Go to the Unanswered tab in any SE.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I meant having a rep requirement to vote to accept in someone else's question. Wouldn't want someone just making a few extra accounts to propel themselves.

Comment: Um... unanswered is only for questions with no answers with upvotes. It shouldn't show questions with upvoted answers.

Comment: @Catija True. Negative point answers still showed up. Did you get your Timey Wimey hat? Most of the old posts were either ID questions without answers or questions without accepted answers.

Comment: "Allow others to 'accept' an answer" is second on the hit parade to "force voters to explain downvotes". This has been discussed _to death_.

Comment: Not giving so much prominence to the accepted answer is probably a more viable "solution". See [Keeping special status for Accepted Answers without sticking them to top forever?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268666/21960)

Comment: @AlE. When our achievements aren't based on expected answers as well, I can see it being plausible.

Answer (score 6):

When a user accepts an answer, the meaning attached is "This was most helpful to *me*".

We have always maintained that accepting answers is not required. In such cases, the best answer will get the most community votes.

This is not a problem and does not need to be solved.